# How to translate the English imperative 'See: X' when referencing?

Tags: translation, imperative

In a reference like *See: Page 234* or *See: requests*,
how is that done in German?

Since neither English nor German is my native language, I hesitate to write *Sehe*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you can use "[siehe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/siehe)":

> Siehe Seite XXX

Answer (score 9):

You should use *[siehe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/siehe)* for this.

Some example usages:

> Siehe Seite 234. – See page 234.
>
> Siehe Seite 234 f. – See page 234 and following page.
>
> Siehe Seite 234 ff. – See page 234 and following pages.
>
> s. S. 234 ff. [shortened version of the above]

We also use *siehe* if we are not referencing to a book page, for example:

> Siehe Anlagen.
>
> Siehe Anfragen.

Comment: Vielleicht der Vollständigkeit halber: Da *siehe* oft in Klammern in der Mitte eines Satzes steht und nicht am Satzanfang, schreibt man es normalerweise klein.